# Keras RNN not training on all training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create a RNN for the purpose of taking EEG data and outputting a score out of 10 corresponding to the participant's enjoyment of the video they watched while receiving the EEG. I have separated all of my EEGs into a training set 1152 EEGs strong and a test set with 128, but when I initiate the training of my model, it tells me its training between 36 EEGs each epoch instead of the full training set. If it matters, each EEG is 32 channels of 8064 points (128Hz for 60s). Most values are just placeholders that were to be tweaked once the model worked properly.

```
X, y = getXY()
x_test = X[:np.size(X,0)//10,:,:]
y_test = y[:np.size(y,0)//10]
x_train = X[np.size(X,0)//10:,:,:]
y_train = y[np.size(y,0)//10:]

print(x_train.shape) #(1152,32,8064)
print(x_test.shape) #(128, 32, 8064)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:]), activation="relu", return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Running this code will eventually trigger the keras output that shows the progress of the current epoch, but it says *(some number)*/36 instead of *(other number)*/1152.

Comment: I've learned that the number I am referring to is the batch size, which means I have many other issues but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The default keras batch size is 32:

> batch_size     Integer or NULL. Number of samples per gradient update. If
> unspecified, batch_size will default to 32.

https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/fit.html

Since you did not set it to 1 you have 1152/32=36 batches that are executed per epoch.